# Chromium installed via Snap regularly only display "sigtrap" for new tabs

Tags: snap, chromium

On my new Ubuntu 20.10. i wanted to try out Chromium via a snap package installation, in the past i always used the native binaries via the ubuntu repository. So i installed Chromium v90.0.4430.93 via snap.

I usually have Chromium up and running for multiple days with quite some load: i use it to monitor cryptocurrency via multiple cryptowat.ch tabs (4-6). Maybe this usage is part of the problem?

After some time (like days) i cannot open new tabs. I only get a Chromium error page showing "Errorcode: SIGTRAP". The screenshot is localized to german:

[image]

Restarting Chromium fixes this problem and it behaves normally for some time again, before beaking again.

Anybody got an idea what is going on? Or how to debug this problem further?

Edit: Like so many times: Just after posting i got a new clue: The Chromium snap was auto-refreshed this morning a 00:44am. So maybe that is the problem i am facing: The snap is up and running and in the background snapd updates the snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the reason for this: It is a known bug for the Chromium Snap when the application is running while the snap is updated in the background.

See this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1914918

Answer (score 0):

A potential fix as provided, [indirectly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1914918/comments/11), in another answer...

`sudo snap set system experimental.robust-mount-namespace-updates=false`

WARNING: *Side effects and trade offs unknown.*

---

Maybe a useful clue...

Notice that an "Update" is indicated in the corner.
[image]

Comment: To solve the problem, this should be set to `true`, which will one day be the default: [Refresh App Awareness - call for testing](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/refresh-app-awareness-call-for-testing)

Comment: You'll likely start getting this notification: "_Close the app to avoid disruptions_". TBD: **What should you actually do when this happens?**

Comment: In 22.04, there is progress (regarding `snap`), but still confusion (and a major nuisance introduced for Firefox): [pending update of "firefox" snap Close the app to avoid disruptions](https://askubuntu.com/q/1412140/11522)