# How to solve "Pending update of "firefox" snap. Close the app to avoid disruptions" error?

Tags: firefox, snap

Recently, this warning appears when open Firefox:

> Pending update of "firefox" snap
>
> Close the app to avoid disruptions

What does it mean? And what do I have to do? Is this a bug?

Comment: Alternatively, replace the snap version of Firefox with apt version, so that you control when firefox will update (and it won't interrupt when you are doing some important work).

Comment: There are several browsers available in the Software Boutique. Not all of them are managed by `snap`. One solution that may work for a lot of people is to use Chrome or Brave, etc.

Comment: Same for Chromium. Is driving me mad. Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/v3ixag/pending_update_of_chromium_snap_close_the_app_to/ | https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/refresh-app-awareness-call-for-testing/29123/8

Comment: just a comment: why can Firefox / Chromium give us a hint of what to do ? Rather than send a totally ambiguous statement out day after day until we have to go out and search for answer. Lack of intelligent documentation is such a waste of time - for everyone.

Comment: The snap notification "*Pending update of "XYZ snap Close the app to avoid disruptions*," introduced in 22.04, is an enormous improvement over the older behavior...where the app would simply terminate without warning in order to update, seeming like a crash. Folks who want to improve the experience should get involved, contribute code, and make other meaningful contributions. Complaining about it here accomplishes nothing.

Comment: I just want to comment the current status quo is better than before.  Before, apt would upgrade firefox (since it's considered a security update), firefox would show that bar saying it must be restarted, and you could not open new tabs until you restarted firefox.   Now, there's a notification that I thought meant an update would occur as soon as I quit firefox, and turns out it won't.  Fine by me, personally rather than force the update I'll let it update when it wishes too.

Comment: This UX is terrible. Because if you close firefox nothing will happen. The message should be "close the app and do a refresh by yourself, or I will notify you again".

Comment: I wrote a script that detects this, and detects when the application is closed, and performs `snap-update` for you automatically, to address this issue. https://gitlab.com/rahvee/snap-update  Unfortunately, for some reason, stackexchange has a stupid login system, and I logged in with a new account, and I cannot post an answer because my new account doesn't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: That's annoying as hell. Just wanted to make it public that this was the last straw for me, and what made me ditch Ubuntu for real.

Comment: @hwertz No, you are wrong. Previously, when Firefox was installed by apt, you could decide when and if apt will update Firefox. It only happened automatically (as you describe) if you configured it to do so (yes, it was the default, but you could change it). With snap, there is no configuration option to decide when and if updates should be installed, they are always automatic. So it's worse, not better. That "pending update" message is just a poor workaround for this.

Comment: True.  I have apt set to not even download regular updates, but kept it set to auto-install security updates; and firefox is always considered a security update.  I don't know why I put quite that positive a spin on what snap is doing, it really is getting old to have it pop up that message, then when you do close firefox find that snap has blown away the update and has to download it again.  Having no control over snap's update schedule really is no good, and I'm getting tempted to find a firefox ppa or something so I can remove snap like I did in 20.04.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If you have received a notification of a pending Firefox update it will appear as a small bell icon next to the clock in the top panel. Clicking on the bell will show a Firefox pending update notification as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

As soon as you see the `Pending update of "firefox" snap. Close the app to avoid disruptions (13 days left)` notification (which means you have 13 days to upgrade Firefox yourself or else the Firefox snap package will get an unattended upgrade) close Firefox and then reopen it after updating the Firefox snap package is finished. If the pending update to the Firefox snap package has not started yet, it can be initiated by running `sudo snap refresh`. If you don't close Firefox after Firefox has finished being  updated, then you will be unable to open any new tabs until you close Firefox and then reopen it.

When the Firefox snap package has been updated a notification will appear that Firefox was updated and is ready to launch.

[image]

Another noteworthy feature of pending updates for Firefox is that they can be installed automatically without user interaction. For example, I have closed Firefox, locked the screen, and left the computer for a few minutes, and then when I came back I received a notification that a pending update to Firefox had been installed in my absence.

---

The Firefox update notification has changed since this question was asked. Now it looks like this.

[image]

The bottom notification says that Software updates are available to be downloaded. When I ignore this notification on my Ubuntu 22.04 the software updates are downloaded automatically. The top and more recent notification says:

```
Update available for Firefox.
Close the application to update now. It will update.
```

As soon as I close the Firefox window, Firefox starts to update, and a few seconds later I get another notification that says:

```
Firefox was updated.
Ready to launch.
```

The second screenshot in this answer shows an image of this notification which is the third of three Firefox update notifications. I consider these 3-step notifications to be an improvement on the original notification because because when I close Firefox it only takes a few seconds for Firefox to be updated and ready to launch. If I select *History* -> *Restore Previous Session* in Firefox, then all my tabs from the previous session come back.

Comment: I,ve done this sequence: 
Close firefox.
Command in Terminal: sudo snap refresh. And now it's Ok

Comment: Another example of snap wanting to have some feature without implementing proper UI support. We want Android style permissions, but we won't have Android-style permission prompt popups, we'll make you dig through settings to find out what's wrong. We want to force you to close the app to allow an update, but we won't detect that the app closed and update visibly automatically, go do it yourself in a terminal.

Comment: It's true, Google is usually very good with user interface features. Ubuntu developers could learn a lot from Google.

Comment: I'm also running into this, and even though `sudo snap refresh` seems to fix it, i wonder what the intended behavior is and why it doesn't work. I generally keep things up to date and a restart of firefox definitely doesn't resolve this issue.

Comment: To spell this out, `sudo snap refresh` while firefox is running shows no snaps to update, run it after `killall firefox` and it does update.

Comment: What is the meaning of the "X days remaining" warning? After that many days it stops notifying? Or it forces something?

Comment: @user272901 As soon as you see the "X days remaining" warning (which means you have X days to upgrade Firefox yourself or else the Firefox snap package will get an unattended upgrade) immediately close Firefox, open the terminal, run `sudo snap refresh` and you're done! The Firefox snap package is now upgraded to the latest version.

Comment: I believe that this is not really answer to the problem, just workaround. Application should be updated seamlessly without disrupting user workflow. Do you know if there is a bug?

Comment: @ĽubomírMlích If this is to be reported to Launchpad as a bug it should be noted that the "X days remaining" warning notification is not unique to the Firefox snap package. This notification may also appear for a pending updates of other snap packages. In other words the updates to snap packages should be applied seamlessly globally.

Comment: Is there any reason why the update isn't performed/pre-staged in the background? The message made me assume that the new version is already installed and once I close and restart Firefox, I'll be running the new version. Isn't this exactly what snap should allow (keeping the old version while its running while also installing the new version)?

Comment: @JanSchejbal I've seen both cases. To be absolutely sure that Firefox is updated to the latest version you can run `sudo snap refresh firefox`

Comment: @JackM is so true it hurts

Comment: Why even force updates? This is not Windows. The want to bring Microsoft update philisophy here of forced updates. I don't like having to re-open my programs and re-creating my environments. So stupid

Comment: It's mainly a security issue. Hackers keep getting better all the time and  web browsers need to be updated frequently to prevent zero-day exploits.

Comment: Thanks friend, this is the right answer. I got notification for VSCode. Personally, I hate snap packages, they are too slow to start. But previous store software are really fast. Also in notification they have to mention this (how to do). New comers to ubuntu will suffer from this.

Comment: I know how to solve the snaps are slow to start problem. My workstation has 32GB RAM and Firefox snap jumps right up on Ubuntu 22.04 as soon as I click the Firefox icon in the Dock. All the snaps launch similarly fast except for Typora that makes me wait 30 seconds to enter "Not now" in the "Activate Typora Enter a license code to support our development" window.

Comment: :) My friend @karel, That means Ubuntu 22.04 needs muscles systems.

Comment: Terrible UX. I appreciate that they are trying to make snap Firefox better, but this kind of update should not be prompted to user that frequently, for whole 13 days. If I don't want to manually update, then just auto update and don't bother me.

Comment: what is a snap "unattended upgrade"? IS that where the update is forced including a forced kill of firefox? Can these be triggered from the command line? I can't find snap documentation for "unattended upgrades"

Comment: @TimRichardson Here is an example of a snap unattended upgrade: I saw this notification in the panel: `Pending update of "Snap Store" snap. Close the app to avoid disruptions (13 days left)` so I opened my terminal and ran `sudo snap refresh` but nothing was upgraded because the Snap Store had already been upgraded in the background by an unattended upgrade.

Comment: @karel That sounds like a normal snap period upgrade attempt that succeeded because the app was fortuitously not in use when one of the four times a day background upgrade jobs ran. If you kept the snap store open all the time, would it have updated? Because Firefox doesn't. 'Unattended upgrade' sounds more like a forced upgrade that occurs despite the app being open ... otherwise, what's the point of the countdown in the notification if at the end of it, nothing happens?

Comment: @TimRichardson Sometimes a snap unattended upgrade occurs even when the app is open, in which you get a notification to close the app and reopen it before doing any more actions in it. If you try to perform a new action anyway the app won't respond. There is more great related information at this question: [Pending Update of Snap Store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store).

Comment: Agreed that this is a horrible UX experience.  I have used Ubuntu and Firefox going back as far as 2006 and have always been diligent about software updates when prompted.  I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 two days ago (six hour process, but quite smooth) and have experienced 2 "crashes" of Firefox since.  Only after internet search did I learn that this is a consequence of conversion from apt to snap.  While I followed the "close firefox / sudo snap refresh / re-open firefox" sequence, I got back only one of the two windows I had open in Firefox and then had to re-start all my extensions.

Comment: Snap can also be just broken. I have snap reporting that the package I am getting this notification about (in my case MS Teams for Linux) is up to date hence `snap refresh` doesn't yield any results.

Comment: @rbaleksandar The snap is either broken or maybe the notification is from the Snap Store and it's obsolete, but it hasn't been removed from the Snap Store yet.

Answer (score 67):

The above only works if you actually close firefox, otherwise the snap will not refresh, and running snap refresh will not even tell that it held an update back.

The formula that worked for me:

```
killall firefox;
sudo snap refresh;
```

But the user experience sucks. It was far more slick using `apt`, and starting firefox on older machines seems quite a lot slower too.

Comment: The "killall" element solved my issue

Comment: Same with Telegram too, which is what I was having a problem with. Make sure it is really closed and not just minimized before doing the refresh.

Comment: Even rebooting does not make the message go away. As phm says: the user experience sucks.

Answer (score 47):

**How to disable `snap` notifications on the Settings UI**

This is not ideal as you will miss out on the latest security updates. But if the thing is going to keep annoying me every other day, I can't stand it anymore.

- Settings ("Windows key" and search "Settings")
- Notifications
- Snapd User Session Agent
- Slide Notifications left

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04. Learnt from: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-disable-snapd-update-notifications-permanently/31117/2

It is not like I leave my laptop on suspend every night, I shut it down every day, thus shutting down the browser, and even then the update is not automatic. That system is just too user unfriendly. Devs need to implement a system that automatically downloads security updates, and that they take effect when you restart the program. A notification should only show e.g. after 24 hours of being outdated.

Bibliography:

- [Pending Update of Snap Store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/v1s919/disable_pending_update_of_snap_message_kiosk/

[image]

Comment: I agree, it is extremely annoying, why don't  the add an option to automatially download the update, and apply the update on the next restart of the app [just like expo updates :)]

Answer (score 31):

The message says...

> Close the app to avoid disruptions

It would be more helpful if it told you to close the app, *and leave it closed for a day or so (with the computer running)*, to allow the pending update to occur in the background. The assumption is that this process, itself, will not be a "disruption".

The faster solution, assuming you're willing to put up with `snap` shenanigans, is to run `snap refresh --list` in order to identify any pending updates, then close the associated apps before running `sudo snap refresh`, then repeat this sequence to make sure you were successful.

Here's a session log, further demonstrating that you can't take `snap` messages at face value. Hopefully, there's enough hints here to make `snap` updates more manageable.

```
$ sudo snap refresh
All snaps up to date.

$ snap refresh --list
Name      Version        Rev   Size   Publisher   Notes
chromium  103.0.5060.53  2020  139MB  canonical✓  -

$ snap refresh --time
timer: 00:00~24:00/4
last: today at 14:55 MDT
next: today at 19:03 MDT
```

Comment: On the plus side (assuming you have enough expertise to deal with this successfully) these popups make it more obvious when your browser(s) need to be patched.

Comment: I got a similar notification about another application. I then gave the command `sudo snap refresh`, which yielded the output `All snaps up to date.` Only *after* I'd closed the offending application, and tried the refresh command again, was the application updated. Very odd.

Comment: The warning message is clearly deficient in that it seems to imply that ALL you have to do is close the app.  The SNAP daemon knows that it is dependent upon Firefox being shut down.  Why does the Snap Daemon not ask for a NOTIFICATION when Firefox does shut down and automatically start the refresh?  I haven't tried a reboot.  Does anybody know if a reboot includes an automatic snap refresh?  Somehow APT managed to update Firefox without requiring this much intervention from the user.

Comment: how early can snap refresh be scheduled during boot?

Comment: @JamesCobban Yes I tried rebooting, and no (ubuntu 22.04) it doesn't automatically snap refresh.

Comment: [Ubuntu 22.04] I've just been ignoring this notification. Suddenly (after several days of warnings), I see a notification something like "snap updating now". The app never stopped running -- newly launched instances use the newer version. It turns out that the only "disruption" was the notifications themselves. Perhaps I want to close the old versions, eventually, in order to be fully patched.

Comment: [pkill -f chromium-browser/chrome](https://superuser.com/a/1297082/114579)

Comment: On Ubuntu 23.04 and newer, snapd now downloads in the background, immediately updates when the application is terminated, and notifies when the application can be restarted. On these releases of Ubuntu, there is no longer a need to leave closed for long periods.

Answer (score 7):

Firefox deb packages are available from mozillateam PPA.

Shot instructions:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
# raise firefox PPA priority
echo -e 'Package: firefox*\nPin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam\nPin-Priority: 501' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozillateamppa
sudo apt remove firefox
sudo apt install firefox
```

#### Remark

The PPA repo has a higher Pin-Priority, but after two days, the snap package was installed again.

I've done the following:

```
apt list --all-versions firefox
sudo apt install firefox=105.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1
sudo apt-mark hold firefox
```

#### Update firefox

```
sudo apt upgrade firefox
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an all GUI, app specific solution:

- Close the app in need of updating
- Open the Ubuntu Software app
- Click "Installed" (to list only software already on your machine)
- Click on the app to update
- Click "Update"

Comment: Some applications remain running when the application window is closed (snap-store is one example). The user must actively Quit those applications.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a bug in the update or update message system (Possibly related to FireFox).

I keep seeing the alert message in the System Messages notification area:

[image: firefox update message]

However, there is no actual update for firefox available.

I am running the current version which is available from snap.

[image: firefox version]

If I look in the Snap store it shows there are actually no updates.

[image: snap store no updates]

However, when I look at the version in the snap store it does display the [Install] button (as if it is not installed).

However, you can see that both versions (107.0.1) are the same.

[image: firefox 107.0.1]

And yet this message keeps popping up each day.  It always says 13 days left also.

Comment: it just keeps getting better and better.  / sarcasm

Comment: Hey I have this same exact bug with Firefox on 22.04 so did you ever find a solution for it?

Comment: @Cool124  Seems to be a bug because I see the latest version of FireFox released and it is giving the message again -- even though I already have the latest version installed.  I have not found any solution at this point.

Comment: @raddevus Yeah you're not the only one with that bug. Hey you should report it to Canonical as a bug, you can report bugs to Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: This bug is now long fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If the notification still popups after the suggested `killall offending_process_name`, try running:

```
sudo snap refresh [offending_process_name]
```

Replacing `[offending_process_name]` for the name of what you are trying to update. If you don't know the name, you can use `sudo snap refresh --list` to get it.

Why? Because that one will fail too, but it will tell you why it fails for that specific package. It will produce an output similar to this:

```
Cannot update [offending_process] because it has associated apps running.
```

And most important, it will tell you the `PIDs` of the associated processes in the next line. Once you know the `PIDs`, you can simply run:

```
sudo kill 44332
sudo kill 55434
```

Where those numbers are some random PIDs. Replace for the real ones.

Then retry:

```
sudo snap refresh [offending_app]
```

or `sudo snap refresh` and it should work this time.

Real life example: Visual Studio Code seems to spawn processes like Android's ADB, omnisharp, etc. And in some situations it doesn't close them on exit. This result in a peculiar situation. You run `killall code`, **code** is the command name to launch Visual Studio Code, and you get that the process isn't running at all. Then you retry `sudo snap refresh` and it doesn't update code, and just produce the popup saying "you have XX days to...".

It seems like snap tracks the processes launched by snaps even if they aren't snaps themselves (**comment on this**). The `PIDs` you pass to `kill` command may not be snaps. If this is the case, then spawning things from the **builtin terminal** may too prevent update even when `code` is not in memory.

Also, if for some reason kill doesn't end those processes you have to force the `SIGKILL` signal, default is `SIGTERM` and won't kill bugged processes. See `man kill`.

Answer (score 1):

Just close Firefox and then run these commands:

```
sudo snap refresh
sudo snap refresh firefox
```

Comment: If you "Just close the firefox"  you also still have to explicitly tell SNAP to refresh.  For some reason this is not automatically triggered when Firefox shuts down.  I tried.  Finally when you restart Firefox you have lost your current working environment.  It might have taken hours to get to the specific set of open windows.  Instead the message does not warn you that you need to KILL your Firefox tasks, for example by rebooting.

Comment: "snap refresh --list" command lists all snaps need to be refreshed

Comment: No matter how much snap refreshing, upgrading, and updating I do, the message keeps coming back.  The only cure for the problem is to have some kind of automatic updating