# Pending Update of Snap Store

Tags: snap, update-manager, snap-store

What's with 'Pending Update of Snap Store?'

[image]

Comment: Related for Firefox: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412140/pending-update-of-firefox-snap-close-the-app-to-avoid-disruptions

Comment: This question has been locked, so I cannot add a new answer. Here is a better answer. I wrote a script that detects when the app is closed, and automatically performs the `snap refresh` for you. https://gitlab.com/rahvee/snap-update

Comment: I submitted a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1998233 As usual, the best way for something to get done about this is to go to the bug report, and near the top click _Does this bug affect you_ > _Yes, it affects me_

Comment: I quit Slack for few seconds, snap updated it immediately and voila notification is gone!

Answer (score 547, accepted):

There are a couple things happening.

**First**, let's talk about **the EASIEST way to make the notification go away**:

1. Quit the application -- in this case, snap-store (a.k.a. Ubuntu Software). Since snap-store auto-starts upon login, you might not recall that you have it open...but you do.

   - **Closing the window is not enough** to terminate the application.
   - One way: On the command line, run `snap-store --quit`
   - Another way: Open Ubuntu Software, look at the top bar, find "Ubuntu Software" on the left side of the top bar. Click it, and select "Quit".
     [image]
2. Run `sudo snap refresh`. Let the command complete.

   - If, instead of a refresh, you still get a pop-up that the application needs to be refreshed, then run `sudo snap refresh <application-name>`.
      The output of that command will return the PID causing the block.
      Use `kill <pid>` to remove the block.
     Run `sudo snap refresh` again. This time it should work.
3. It's now safe to re-launch your application.

   - If you were not using the application before, or you don't know how to launch the application, then you can safely ignore this step.

**Second**, let's talk about **WHY it's happening**:

Snapd detects when a new version is available. If the application is currently running, snapd will *inhibit* updating that application for up to 14 days.

With most applications, this works fine. You Quit out of an application, a few hours later snapd updates the application (it checks several times each day). and the next time you open the application you don't even notice that it's been updated. Great!

But some applications are open for a long time that runs up against that 14-day window. Like web browsers on laptops that get closed/suspended instead of quit/restarted. Unfortunately, when the 14-day window expires, snapd will kill the application in order to implement the upgrade. To the user, this looks like Firefox crashed unexpectedly, losing whatever they were doing.

- Snapd MUST refresh snaps. That's a legacy of the original design; snaps were originally designed for phones and IOT devices that MUST work reliably and MUST update reliably without user input. You can disable it if you know how...but it's a bad idea for most users -- disabling updates means no security patches and insecure applications.

**Third**, let's talk about why you are suddenly **getting these notifications NOW**.

The Snap developers were dissatisfied with those two choices (kill the application to force the upgrade -or- disable upgrades entirely), so [they created a better path](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/refresh-app-awareness-call-for-testing/29123): Remind the user to Quit the application when convenient. **That is the notification you are seeing.** It's new (turned on by default) in Ubuntu 22.04.

- If you ignore it, then when the countdown reaches zero snapd will terminate the application and refresh that snap automatically.

**Finally**, there's one obvious question remaining: **Why isn't this automatic?** or perhaps **Why doesn't snapd download the update *before* nagging you?**

Well, it IS automatic in Ubuntu 23.04 and newer. But that feature is too new for 22.04 users.

- Most folks who encounter this issue simply have not used long-lived Snap-packaged desktop applications before. It's a known problem, and various developers are working on it. You are welcome to help them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138386/discussion-on-answer-by-user535733-pending-update-of-snap-store).

Comment: The key point here is very simple. 

snap will restart automatically if you quit it and it starts when you boot. It can't update a piece of sw when said sw is running. All these answers reflect that what needs to happen is that snap needs stopping and then you can use it from the cli to update itself. Alternatively, you could just leave it to its own devices and (I strongly suspect) after a week or two it will force update itself.

Comment: The application *snap-store* can be closed from the command line. Do `$ snap-store --quit` then `$ sudo snap refresh` will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Pay attention when checking the pids, as some processes may be critical (e.g., the desktop environment). I just killed it

Comment: @Daniel added your suggestion to the answer. Thank you!

Comment: "You might not recall that you have it open, but you do." - definitely not open, this even occurs right after a login with nothing open or clicked.

Comment: @Mendhak thanks. Edited to specify that snap-store autostarts upon login.

Comment: @raj I would not go so far as to say snap is not mature enough to be used in production.  Certbot, for example, is now snapped by default for *most* lInux distros now and works **fine** in production.  Additionally, `rdap` - a tool for getting IP WHOIS info - also works fine in prod out of the box.  There's a ton of snaps that are **completely suitable** for production, despite some odd update quirks here or there.  That does not mean that you can (here at least) simply decree that "snaps are not mature enough for production.  (1/2)

Comment: @raj (case in point for example: the LXD snap has been stable enough for prod use for **years**) (2/2)

Comment: i suppose a way we could work around this would be to disable the notification for the snap-store......or not start snap-store on login 
Where would be the appropriate place to start a discussion around this?

Comment: @ThomasWard I didn't mean snap as the individual applications packaged as snaps. I did mean snap as a **software distribution system** is not mature enough.

Comment: I quit, opened up terminal and got the popup... sudo snap refresh showed all up tp date. Opened up Ubuntu Software again and it showed me the PID, which I killed and successfully used 'sudo snap refresh'. thx

Comment: @Levente that may be a suggestion you make to Ubuntu, to see if they can fix the UX.

Answer (score 129):

I had the same issue, the notification shows that the snap involved is snap-store.

If you run this in terminal, you will get a process ID (PID):

```
sudo snap refresh snap-store
error: cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software), pids:
       2452
```

Then in the terminal kill that process and run it again:

```
kill 2452
sudo snap refresh snap-store
```

and it should succeed.

The currently highest rated answer suggests that you have this running or minimized, but it seems to me it is just running without a user starting it and it does not show running in the dock.
It looks like a bug to me.
As mentioned, it should fix itself after 14 days by killing the application, which may just be inconvenient if you're in the middle of using it.

Seems a work in progress, so perhaps some patience is in order, but if you don't have that, file a bug as described here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: I assume it is always running when checking for snap updates. Maybe this is a deadlock and the update of snap-store should be handled some other way.

Comment: The bug has been reported here: [snap-store can't be updated due to autostart](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1998233) .
Please, go to the bug report and near the top click `Does this bug affect you > Yes, it affects me`

Answer (score 51):

Works for me:

1. Kill "snap" at System Monitor
2. ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
   ```
3. ```
   sudo snap refresh
   ```

Comment: this is what worked for me. thanks!

Comment: or
killall snap-store

Comment: would know all drugs used during snap development process

Comment: Step 1: `snap-store --quit`

Answer (score 4):

```bash
# Close all open `snapd` process
sudo killall -s KILL snapd
sudo snap refresh
```

Comment: IMHO might be worth to use `-SIGTERM | -TERM` instead of the `KILL` to allow the graceful shut down.

Comment: If you need to update the `snap-store` snap then substitute `snapd` for `snap-store` for `killall`

Comment: It is better to use quit command for snap-store: `snap-store --quit`, not to kill it. Then `sudo snap refresh`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
sudo snap refresh
sudo snap install snap-store
```

I needed sudo in front of snap refresh to get it to work.  This was the only option that worked for me.  I also had to start Ubuntu Software app twice.

This also cleared a Snap Store pending update that could no be updated because the Snap Store was running.

Comment: I only needed the first line really

Comment: This overkill, you just need to kill snap-store

Comment: @exebook I mean... technically that's true if you want the message to go away, but you're also removing the store entirely. Up to you I guess...

Answer (score 2):

Close all apps in your Ubuntu. Open Ubuntu Software app, under updates section, update the apps one by one. This trick worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue following these steps:

1. log out from the graphical interface and start a command line session (CTR+ALT+F2 from the system login page).
2. log in with your username and password and run
   `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and then
   `sudo snap refresh`.
3. log out and start back the Ubuntu graphical interface (CTR+ALT+F).

I suppose that the issue is related to the gnome session which seems to run on snap.

Answer (score 1):

In my case was a "Pending update of 'deja-dup" snap...'" so my two penny solution is open a terminal and type:

```
sudo killall deja-dup-monitor
sudo snap refresh
deja-dup&
```

(latest command runs deja-dup's GUI so that deja-dup-monitor is automatically restarted)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and for me works:

```
sudo snap refresh snap-store
```

It will be downloading the necessary packages and at the end it should show you a message like:

> snap-store (stable/ubuntu-22.04) 41.3-60-gfe4703a from Canonical✓ refreshed

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Please kill snap store first. Then run **sudo snap refresh** snap-store will be automatically updated.

Comment: snap-store --quit is the solution to leave snap-store

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to **refresh** the snap store. First, you need to `kill` it using its `pid`.

You can get it by running `sudo snap refresh`, get the `pid` from the output message:

```
error: cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps
       (ubuntu-software), pids: 7274
```

Run: `kill 7274`. Then, run: `sudo snap refresh` again. That's it!

> > To be more specific to the question, use `sudo snap refresh snap-store`, by defining the application name.