# Pending update of snap store (2)

Tags: command-line, updates, snap-store

Pending Update of Snap Store ... still. The answers on [Pending Update of Snap Store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store) aren't working for me (or maybe I'm just not understanding them correctly).
Tried several of the ideas posted but still 'Pending Update of Snap Store' pops up.

Answer from User535733:

> Quit the application (in this case, snap-store [a.k.a. Ubuntu Software]). You might not recall that you have it open, but you do. Maybe it's minimized. Find it and Quit the application.

Can find Snap (when I press 'see hidden files') ... but can't see it's open. How can I close it?.

If I tentatively assume that it is already closed, and proceed with `sudo snap refresh`, the answer is `all snaps up to date`.

> Re-launch your application.

OK … how to do that?

When snap/snap store is an application, why can't I see it under settings/applications?

Second and third parts of that answer, as I understand it, the error is that the snap store needs to be updated (even though it says 'all snaps up to date') because it hasn't been closed for 2 weeks, even though I've only had the computer for 10 days (and can't update when it's open) ... and if it doesn't (because i can't figure out how), it just that snap then shuts itself down and updates itself. Is that correctly understood? (no big disaster waiting to happen, then)

Do I have to open snap manually then?

Will this be a recurring problem (annoying pop-up) every 2 weeks?

answer from mrjusepelo:

> ```
> sudo snap refresh snap-store
> ```

returns "snap-store" has no updates available. But how can they be 'Pending' then?

When I run

`sudo apt-get upgrade` it shows that:

```
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
```

Is that as it should be?

Edit: The problems here, are probably my lack of understanding of the answers in the other thread, not understanding the lingo. And that I didn't understand rather elementary things like how to close an app, or that snap-store and Ubuntu software are the same (I'll bet I'm not the only beginner who didn't get that) ... and knowing that also gives the answer to 'When snap store is an application', why can't I see it under settings/applications? well you can, as Ubuntu software (Thanks to 535733 for input).
I have gradually figured most of it out (I hope) ... but I see my question as an example, of how difficult it is to be new :)

So, only question left: When 'sudo snap refresh snap-store' returns "snap-store" has no updates available, how can they be 'Pending' then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pending Update of Snap Store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store)

Comment: no ... thats the one I call 'another post'

Comment: This doesn't matter. If the problem is the same, the solution should be added to the existing post, not a new one. This is why we flag as duplicates.

Comment: the problem is that the solution dont work for me ... as I write, maybe I'm just not understanding them correctly and thats the problem

Comment: Artur, please ... I sense that you are unhappy with my question, but I do not understand what I am doing wrong. My attempts to get something explained are not 'duplicate'.

Comment: Hi Jack. I'm sorry if I gave that impression. The point here is that a similar question should only exist once on the site. If the existing solutions do not work, we could hope that someone finds a new solution and adds that to the existing question. If you would like to discuss this further, please ask a question on the [Meta site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/), which is geared to these kinds of topics. Thanks. 

Comment: It's not that I want to discuss terms ... but how is it duplicative to ask further when the answers don't work / are not understood ... and I can't do that in the original question, since I don't have the rep. (I'm new here). And I cant write in chat  either.

Comment: The Question seems to conflate `snap` and `snap-store`. `snap` is a terminal command for controlling snapd, the service that handles the unpacking, updating, and sandboxing of snap packages. `snap-store` is an application (also known as Ubuntu Software) that provides your pretty app store . Despite the similarity of names, they are completely different, do different things, and have different developers.. Trying to kill or update one won't affect the other.

Comment: If you get the "pending updates" pop-up *specifically naming* `snap-store` then try the command `sudo snap refresh snap-store` (exact name and correct capitalization are important!), and post the exact, complete input and output in your Question above. Also, you should not need to reboot your system merely to re-launch an application that you're not actually using anyway. Re-launching the application is unnecessary, merely a convenience for folks who were using their application before.

Comment: Thanks ... I found a way to close snap-store, so I'm waiting to see if your solution works now ... but telling me that snap-store and Ubuntu software are the same is AHA (but why not use just one name ... and if they are completely different, why is snap-store a folder in snap). Also good to know relaunching is not necessary (but you told me to, in you answer)

Comment: "*but why not use just one name[?]*" There is a very long, tangled history there involving several different upstream projects, multiple implementations and re-writes, and several name changes over 10 years. Suffice it to say that using the same name was considered, but would cause even greater problems.

Comment: Edited the duplicate answer to address your comment about restarting. Good point!

Comment: Glad to be of some little use. Think maybe you could also add how to find and close snap store ... just a suggestion, don't underestimate what beginners don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kinda new to this too and I've had this issue cropping up.
Make sure you close the snap-store/software app.
Go to the terminal and type

```
pidof snap
```

This should give you the pid of the snapstore
Then type

```
kill pidnumber
```

Replacing the pidnumber with the number you were given
Then type

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade snap
```

This should upgrade snap whilst all process are not running for it.
Run Snap Store to see if that fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I think my way (closing from System Monitor) is easier ... still unsure about using the terminal. And if they do the same.

Comment: I just had it explained that snap and snap-store are two different things ... so had to try that pidof snap command ... and it doesn't return anything. But if I type pidof snap-store I get a number.
Should there also be addressed to snap-store in the last command?

Answer (score 0):

Found answers to some of my own questions (and I know this is probably so basic that most of you might wonder that one doesn't just know):

One way to close applications is to go into Show Applications, System Monitor, and there find the app you want to close ... right-click and select kill.

You can 'Re-launch your application' simply by restarting the computer.

Most of the rest of my confusion was resolved when 535733 in the notes explained to me that snap-store and Ubuntu Software are the same thing ... copying that info to here, to get a comprehensive answer to my questions.

Comment: The accepted answer on that "other post" that was suggested to you, got updated multiple times since you posted this, and is now containing additional clarifications. I suggest that in its current iteration, that thread has the capacity to clear up the specific confusions that you detailed here.