# System keeps asking me to close and update snap-store, running Software Updater does not help

Tags: updates, 22.04, snap-store

I keep getting notifications like these:

[image]

Only the 'n days left' counter keeps decreasing, it started from 14 two weeks ago and is now down to 3.

What is this and how to get rid of this?

I run the Software Updater, but it doesn't help. Software Updater installs updates and says that "*The software on this computer is up to date*", yet the notification keeps appearing. I find this surprising since the Software Updater also says it updates snaps:

[image]

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: try ```snap refresh``` on the terminal.

Comment: The Ubuntu Software application (snap-store) is running. You might think it's not running because the window is closed or minimized, but it's still running in the background. Open Ubuntu Software and really Quit the application properly. Then you won't be pestered that it's running anymore.

Comment: @user535733 If clicking X in the upper right corner of the Ubuntu Software window is not enough, then how to "*Quit the application properly*"?

Comment: On the Dock, look for the Ubuntu Software icon. Right click. Select "Quit".

Comment: Alternate: Look at the Top Bar of the screen. Left Side of the top bar, look for the "Ubuntu Software" word denoting that it's the active application. Click the word, select Quit. See [this image](https://ubuntucommunity.s3.dualstack.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/optimized/3X/8/8/88159df3518f932d857f92db02ca512a5dcd8c92_2_690x282.jpeg) for example.

Comment: @user535733 thanks! ... (side note: for reasons like these I really don't like this new convention that closing all windows does not close the app!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the terminal and type the following commands:

```
killall snap-store
sudo snap refresh
```

Wait until the second command has finished completely before closing terminal.

Comment: It seems it worked, thank you! I'll wait a day to see if the notification does not return and if it doesn't, I accepted this answer. Side question: Why did this happen in the first place? Am I expected to manually update snap-store in this way all the time? I thought updates were supposed to 'just work'?

Comment: They do generally, but on both my 22.04 instances this message continues occasionally with no specific reason. It's no big deal. If it happens again, open terminal as before and use the ↑ to cycle through your history to refind the commands or use `Ctrl+r` in terminal to search for it.

Comment: This answer expands and provides background: https://askubuntu.com/a/1412580/558158