unable to upgrade snapstore, snap store has a running app
I am trying to upgrade snaps, but it will not grade because snap is running, it says pids: 1955 is on, how do I turn it off so I can upgrade

Possibly related https://askubuntu.com/a/1429871/307670

This question is similar to: Unable to update "Snap Store": cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Go back into Snap store. Select 'Quit'. Merely closing the window is not enough.

Or
snap-store --quit

Or
kill 1955

