# How to stop snap-store for update

Tags: updates, snap-store

I'm confused.
I get a notification that updates to snap-store are waiting. I go into Ubuntu Software and tell it to update snap-store.

I get a message that it can't be done because snap-store has running apps.

It gives me a PIDS.

I go into system monitor and stop the indicated pids.

I open Ubuntu Software to do the update and get the same error message, with a different pids.

How do I get out of this vicious loop?

There seems to be forum discussion about removing snap-store, but I just want to update it and, preferably, without messing with CLI. Since there's a GUI for updating Ubuntu software, why would one have to mess with CLI?

Comment: "Since there's a GUI for updating Ubuntu software, why would one have to mess with CLI?" Because it's poorly implemented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pending Update of Snap Store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Ubuntu Software" and "snap-store" are two names for the same application.

Ubuntu Software (provided by the snap named `snap-store`) cannot be updated while it it running.

When you Quit or kill the application...and then promptly restart it...that means it's running again! So it *still* cannot be updated.

- Ubuntu Software = snap-store
- Snap-store *cannot update itself*
- Ubuntu Software cannot update snap-store (they are two names for the *same application*)

You have two options:

1. Quit the application and *leave it stopped*. Don't restart it. Snapd will update snap-store in the background sometime during the next few hours.
2. Quit the application and use the command line to update the snap immediately: `sudo snap refresh`

For a simple solution:

```
snap-store --quit
sudo snap refresh
```