# How can I dismiss "Software Updates Installed" notification?

Tags: updates, snap, notification, snap-store

For days, Software has been [nagging me to close snap-store so that it can update itself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1430194/how-to-stop-snap-store-for-update).

Now that's resolved and it has finally installed various updates, it shows a notification every time I boot up:

> Software Updates Installed
>
> Important OS updates have been installed
>
> [ Review ]  [ Cancel ]  [ OK ]

No matter whether I click Review, Cancel or OK, it still displays this notification next time I reboot.

How can I dismiss it permanently?

Comment: For persistent `UEFI dbx` update notifications, see using `fwupdmgr clear-results` in https://askubuntu.com/a/1498444.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar but not quite same issue and found that both gnome-software (apt package) and snap-store (snap) were installed... Removing the one I don't use (in my case gnome-software) solved the issue.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Brilliant, that's resolved it for me too. Thank you!

Comment: is dont have gnome software installed at all, but still see the symptoms described above. So that's probably not the root cause. But the removal of gnome-software might delete some files that are responsible for the repeated messaging

Answer (score 8):

I found an old discussion about the problem on the Debian forums (https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=121809)

The solution is to delete the logfile at `/var/lib/PackageKit/offline-update-competed`. This solved the problem for me and is less invasive than removing "gnome-software".

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  It's been driving me a little buggy, and this solved the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately on ubuntu 23.10 I don't have this file to delete. The folder has only a transactions.db file. 
I have the same problem as the author since I upgraded Ubuntu a few days ago.

Comment: @Teo7: You are right, I also upgraded (to 23.04 in my case) and only have the transactions.db file now. This is an SQLite database file. Maybe opening it with an SQLite client and browsing it's entries will give some clues. I didn't have the base problem (the notification message popping up) for a long time and I can't reproduce it, so I am not able to test a solution with changing the SQLite entries.

Comment: Worked for me on 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490410/how-can-i-dismiss-software-updates-installed-notification-the-saga-continues#comment2624247_1493132) that fixed it for me.

```
killall snap-store && sudo snap switch snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10 && sudo snap refresh
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So far this is the only working solution for ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 23.10 the suggested solutions did not work for me.
I managed to resolve the issue by emptying the `/var/log/unattended-upgrades` folder instead.

Comment: I have tried, but sadly nothing changes.. I just see that the file "unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log", which is empty, is recreated at every boot.

Comment: can you describe in more detail what exactly you did? And are you 100% sure that you did not do anything else additionally? 
These files are just logfiles, and in my case dont even contain any string that has to do with the repeated messages -like uefi or dbx. Sounds very unlikely that this is really causing the messages.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the issue above and other related snap-store [bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1430194/how-to-stop-snap-store-for-update) and [failings](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/pending-update-of-snap-store-but-no-update-available/34415), a couple of months ago I removed snap-store:

```
snap remove snap-store
```

This leaves the snap system intact, but just removes the troublesome snap-store.

Instead I now use gnome-software which manages snaps perfectly without any of the above issues. gnome-software also has the advantage that it handles flatpak and DEB packages.