# Ubuntu 22.04 Software Center

Tags: 22.04, software-center

I seem to have two separate software centers, one called Ubuntu Software (orange icon), and one called software (multi-color icon). Neither one loads properly and I have tried sudo apt update, purge, refresh, reinstall, to name a few. Nothing has worked and I get the following error; "libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...." The explore and installed tabs either show nothing at all or the categories don't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your system has several different apparent problems. Please ask about only one. If you want help with the apt problem, add the full output to your question. Copy and paste, no screen shots.

Comment: Indeed, you will also have a problem with the consistency of the package system, which will need to be solved first before anything else.

Comment: The  `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting... error occurred when I attempted to purge and reinstall gnome using sudo apt purge and sudo apt install. I did this based upon another users recommendations but it clearly didn't work. How do I go about fixing this issue? Is this not directly related to the software center issue I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

The orange icon, Ubuntu Software (confusingly "snapstore" in the software apps), is the one distributed with Ubuntu, the other is Gnome Software, which you must have installed and upon which Ubuntu Software is itself based. I have both and I think the reason was to enable flatpacks through an extension. One problem I have is that if my wired network is not switched on before the desktop is loaded both programmes will launch but the software catalogues won't load, and it is impossible to update the system. The solution is to ensure everything is on at boot time or restart the desktop by logging out then back in again.

Oh and I eventually deleted snapstore because I was getting the same notification for updated software at every boot up re:
[How can I dismiss "Software Updates Installed" notification?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469200/how-can-i-dismiss-software-updates-installed-notification)

Answer (score 0):

'sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg' got rid of the other software center and 'snap-store --quit' reset Ubuntu Software, everything works fine now