# Ubuntu Software / Snap Store categories do not load

Tags: snap-store

Ubuntu Software / Snap Store categories do not load. When I select a category it shows blank categories:

[image: Ubuntu Software]

I have tried removing and reinstalling the software from the terminal, bur nothing changes.

Comment: Unfortunately after trying all of these suggestions, it still does not work.

Comment: maybe this one? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1471636/ubuntu-22-04-software-center