# How to restart Ubuntu Software Installer App (Ubiquity?)

Tags: 20.04, software-center, snap, ubiquity

(20.04 LTS) My Ubuntu Software Installer App has disappeared (something was trying to update "snap" but couldn't because some package was running. So I uninstalled 'snap' but that resulted in the orange system Installer icon disappearing from my Favourites bar.)
I tried:

sudo apt-get install ubiquity

which took a v long time... (>500MB) which surprised me...

But then when I typed "ubiquity" in Terminal it said I should use "importlib" so I'm similarly stuck:

> > /usr/bin/ubiquity:74: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
> > import imp
> > Error executing command as another user: Request dismissed

Any suggestions?

Comment: To expand on the prior comment, ubiquity is used for the initial installation of the system. It is not what is used to install software onto your system once that has been done.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that by "*run ubiquity*" what you **really** mean is "*restore the system to proper functioning*"

First, forget about ubiquity. That's the wrong application, and has nothing to do with the problem you described. Ubiquity is the application that installs an entire Ubuntu system from a LiveUSB.

Second, reinstall snapd. You need it to run Ubuntu Software.

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

Finally, reinstall the snap that runs the Ubuntu Software application. The snap is called `snap-store`.

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

Next time you get a notification that "some" application cannot be updated because XYZ is running, DON'T uninstall snapd. There are simpler and easier ways to handle it. [Here's an example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/)

Comment: Thx. All working. Do I need to uninstall the eroneous Ubiquity? (sudo apt-get remove ubiquity)?

Comment: You don't need Ubiquity. You will never use it from your current system. It's safe to uninstall it. Whether or not you uninstall it is entirely up to you.