# Cannot Refresh Snap Store (PID 1805)

Tags: gnome, updates, login, snap, gdm

I know Pending Update questions have been asked and answered, such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store), which seems thorough enough to solve the problem. However, after running a Snap Store update from command line I received this error:

[image]

From what I can gather, PID 1805 is the GNOME Display Manager (GDM) that allows users to login.

My concerns are these:

- GDM is going to be stopped by the Update Manager after X amount of days to be updated, and if I am using the laptop at the time, it will suddenly cut off and I'll lose whatever I was doing.
- I can stop the GDM from the command line, but I've read online where people have done that and been stuck with a black screen, unable to get back to the login screen or the desktop.

Are these fears justified, and if so, what if anything can I do to prevent them?

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME: 42.4
Windowing Sys: Wayland

-- EDIT --
Here is the result of running "ps -aux | grep 1805"
[image]

Comment: Run the command `ps -aux | grep 1805`. Ensure your terminal is wide enough to see the entire output. Copy the complete input and output. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1432375/edit) to paste the complete input and output into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output shows that PID 1805 is NOT gdm, nor gnome-shell, nor anything else critical.

It's merely a snap-store process.

The instruction at https://askubuntu.com/a/1412580/19626 are safe for you to follow.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help out with this, I do appreciate it.