# Boot failure with Ubuntu 20.04 and pending update of snap store

Tags: boot

my workstation running Ubuntu 20.04 (i have no dual boot, Ubuntu is the only system installed) is not able to boot.
Before this event, i had some warnings about snap store user session agent and i tried to solve the issue as reported here ([Pending Update of Snap Store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store)):"Another way: Open Ubuntu Software, look at the top bar, find "Ubuntu Software" on the left side of the top bar. Click it, and select "Quit"."
After this, i restarted and the system doesn't boot anymore, i only see a black screen. I saw many replies recommending to launch grub, but it also fails. The system looks like up and running but the keyboard lights are not even switched on. Then i tried to ping from my laptop but no response.
I couldn't find similar questions and i really hope to have some advices as i'm quite new to Linux in general.
Many thanks

Comment: You have listed three problems (snap-store update, boot to black screen, unable to reach GRUB) that do not seem related, so don't mix them up. Advice: Keep trying to reach GRUB. Don't give up. Be smart about it.

Comment: It could also be that GRUB timeout was not set properly, as the installation was previously done by another person. Do you recommend going for a boot repair?