# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS OS-updates fail to download

Tags: updates, 22.04

I am on Ubuntu 22.04LTS. On startup I get a message: `Pending updates of snap-store store. Close the app to avoid disruptions`. So I close and refresh snap as explained in this post: [Pending Update of Snap Store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store). On the command `sudo snap refresh` I get the response `All snap are updated`. But the message keeps showing, also when I restart the computer.

Then in Software there are OS-updates. When I click on the download-button I get the message. `Download of updates failed: The following packages have unmet dependencies:`.
The message does not say what dependencies are unmet. It simply stops after the colon.

[image]

I don´t know if the two problems are related. I found several posts on the second problem, but none of them solved it for me. I would really like to be able to keep the operating system up to date. What can I do?

sudo apt-get update and upgrade give the following output:

```
    jan@Ubuntu-20-04:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] wachtwoord voor jan: 
Geraakt:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Geraakt:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease           
Geraakt:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease          
Geraakt:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/apandada1/brightness-controller/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Geraakt:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease        
Geraakt:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar                     
jan@Ubuntu-20-04:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd... Klaar
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar 
Opwaardering wordt doorgerekend... Klaar
De volgende pakketten zijn automatisch geïnstalleerd en zijn niet langer nodig:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7
  libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl libfcgi0ldbl libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
  libhtml-template-perl libprotobuf-lite23
Gebruik 'sudo apt autoremove' om ze te verwijderen.
Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.
Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro
De volgende pakketten zijn achtergehouden:
  grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed mysql-client mysql-server
0 opgewaardeerd, 0 nieuw geïnstalleerd, 0 te verwijderen en 4 niet opgewaardeerd.
jan@Ubuntu-20-04:~$
```

Comment: Please post the info about what are the unmet dependencies. Cut and paste into the question.

Comment: The message does not say what dependencies are unmet. It simply stops after the colon.

Comment: Run the sudo apt-get update and the sudo apt-get upgrade in a terminal. Cut and past the info on the errors that will display there.

Comment: There do not seem to be any errors.

Comment: Both commands ran with no errors? If so you have an up to date system.

Comment: I take this kind of strange issues to possibly be coupled with non-english settings; therefore my personal machines ALWAYS have English as system language, possibly with 'local' monetary and numeric settings (currently patched to use 'decimal point' and space as number grouping). The example above is also a pure example on why avoid translations; the interpretation of the text in the question is pure guesswork for me.

Comment: @Hannu, Your point of view concerning non-english settings is very interesting. Is it based on experience? What is the experience? If that solves (some) issues I will gladly change my settings. If you paste the text into translate.google.com it does a very good job on translating it.

Comment: @David, Do you have any idea why software wants me to download os-updates when I am up to date? Could that be a bug?

Comment: If it is not giving any names with the commands I gave you I could not even begin to guess.

Comment: @johannes I cannot give you any specific reproducible error case w.r.t. "english", sorry. Though I have very long experience running English OS setups, and having very few strange failures. I believe this is due to English setups are the ones having been most (thoroughly / hardest / ... ) tested... i.e. by the largest amount of people.

Comment: This looks like [phased updates](https://askubuntu.com/q/1431940/590937). Please don't expect us to paste anything into google translate.

Comment: You can get english output by prepending `LANGUAGE=en` to your command like in `LANGUAGE=en sudo apt update`.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably related to the latest bug, that made Ubuntu store "Snap apps only". [Actually i believe this thread is relevant to this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1723668/how-to-update-snap-store-linux-how-to-update-this). I have same issue on my freshly installed machine.

In short:

```
sudo killall snap-store
sudo snap refresh
```

Refresh will install downloaded fixes and after that everything become "up to date".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).