# Some system icons were replaced with 'prohibition sign' icon

Tags: icons, snap-store

**ISSUE DESCRIPTION:**

Some icons are replaced with 'prohibition sign' icons as shown on the screens:

[Topbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxIuK.png)

[Dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Typj2.png)

[Settings tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw8ls.png)

I guess that a potential reason of this problem is a 'snap-store' update that killed running applications and some other processes. Original icons were replaced from that moment. The issue of 'snap-store' update is described in this thread: [Pending Update of Snap Store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store)

**ATTEMPTS:**

1. Restoring shell theme to 'Yaru-dark' (finally, didn't fix the issue)

Steps:

- Installation and activation of 'User Themes' (https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/19/user-themes/) via Extension Manager
- 'Tweaks' app / 'Appearance' tab / 'Shell' select input set to 'Yaru-dark' [screen with related settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPli5.png)

**QUESTION:**

Is there any way to restore original icons (without system reinstallation)?

**DETAILS:**

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. One of Ubuntu Base updates performed about November 16th 2022 restored system icons.