# Pending snap update configuration option

Tags: snap, notification

Like a lot of users, I have recently run into snap issues where it keeps telling giving me notifications that the apps I'm using will close in 14 days, 13, 12,  etc...  There's a lot of questions already on here about *why* this is happening, and after reading those I now understand why it's happening (in particular [this very well written answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412580/1695031) was quite helpful).

My understanding is that when snap needs to update, it:

- continuously tries to update if the app is not in use
- after 0 days, starts pushing notifications to the user as a warning if it can't
- after 14 days, forcibly kills the existing app and updates

The particular apps in question for me are `vscode`, `brave` and `snap-store`.  The last one might arguably be [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1998233), but the other two are just because I run a desktop system and am in the habit of leaving those apps open for days or weeks at a time.  In this case, the warnings are actually useful to me.  With all that background set up though, here's **my actual question:**

1. I guess just to confirm my assumptions, is my understanding of snap's default behavior (above) correct?
2. Is there any way to adjust either or both of the 0, 14 day values in a configuration somewhere?  Bonus points if that configuration can be done on a per-app basis.
3. If there isn't that configuration presently existing, where would I go to submit a feature request (or to upvote an existing one)

(P.S. I am aware that notifications can be fully suppressed.  that is not what I am looking for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your understanding seems accurate.
2. The notification time period is not configurable. Most folks can find time to spend 100 seconds --day or night-- to refresh sometime during that two week window.

   Two weeks is a long time. If the update includes security patches (often do!), do you really want to be running vulnerable for two more weeks?
3. Feature requests should go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd as a Wishlist Bug. You might browse the bugs first; somebody might have already made such a request.

Comment: I appreciate the info, thanks!

I guess I'm not super put out by the 14 day limit.  It certainly causes less problems elsewhere in the ecosystem.  I think for my use case though, adjusting the 0 day warning trigger to be something like .... 5 days maybe, might just make a lot of notifications go away -- I tend to fully close down every so often anyway.