# How to fix "Pending update of __ snap" on Lubuntu 22.04

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, 22.04, snap, chromium

I'm running fresh installs of Lubuntu 22.04 on several systems but keep getting warnings saying "Chromium Pending update of "chromium" snap.  Close the app to avoid disruptions (X days left).  I close chromium and reopen but the warning eventually reappears and the count down continues.  Reboot does not fix this either.  This also happens with firefox so it seems like a snap issue.  I was experimenting with the settings for desk top notifications from the icon at bottom right of the screen but the icon is now gone.  I can still access the settingsnow  from LXQT settings.  How can I fix this snap update issue?

[image]

Comment: More of an annoying message as opposed to an error. Just ignore. Have not seen a way to make it go away.

Comment: Close CHromium and then run `sudo snap refresh` in a terminal. It's the same as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412140/how-to-solve-pending-update-of-firefox-snap-close-the-app-to-avoid-disruptio?rq=1), just a different snap.