# Pending Update of Firefox Snap - prevent auto update and stop showing message

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, 22.04, snap

> **Pending update of firefox snap**
> Close the app to avoid disruptions (xx days left)

This warning message pretends/says that there are just under 14 days left.
Despite this "long period", the message keeps reappearing all the time.

1. a. Does Firefox get killed when the time period expires to force an update?
   b. If so, how can this be prevented?
2. How can I disable the annoying message that constantly disrupts my work?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this post does not answer the question of whether Firefox is automatically killed and if so, how to prevent it. This post also does not answer the question of how to disable this message on Kubuntu. In Kubuntu, there is no _Snapd User Session Agent_ entry under _Notifications_.

Comment: I have worded question 1 more clearly. The question at 1412140 is "What does it mean? And what do I have to do?" - I think the logical consequence is not necessarily to disable the message, so it's not clear if anyone feels it necessary to present this solution for Kubuntu. That's why I asked this question explicitly.

Comment: If you want to prevent it, use the apt version instead of snap https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2501759?noredirect=1

Comment: According to https://askubuntu.com/a/1424950/298314 the annoying message can be disabled by disabling snap notifications. However, this disables *all* snap notifications, not just these ones.

Answer (score 3):

*a. Does Firefox get killed when the time period expires to force an update?*

**Yes**: When the timer reaches zero, snapd will terminate (kill) Firefox and then refresh (update) the snap. Any unsaved work will be lost when the application is terminated.

The notification is intended to be a better alternative. You can select the time to Quit Firefox on your own schedule and at a convenient place in your workflow.

- Keep in mind that after Quitting Firefox, you must ALSO run `sudo snap refresh`, and wait for the command to complete before restarting Firefox.

*b. If so, how can this be prevented?*

**You cannot** prevent snapd from terminating Firefox. Snaps MUST update -- it's a key feature of snaps from their beginning. Automatic, frequent updates are one of the reasons that Mozilla selected snaps to be their primary package for delivering Firefox.

Snaps originated in phones and devices that must update automatically and reliably without user intervention, and preferably without the user even noticing. The expansion of snap packages into desktop systems is much newer, and there are indeed some teething troubles with snaps for long-lived desktop applications (like Firefox).

Both Mozilla and Canonical engineers continue to work on those bugs. The refresh experience will get better.