# How do I resolve the 'Pending update of "firefox" snap' message?

Tags: firefox, snap

I am getting a message that seems to imply some kind of update for the firefox snap is being held back until I "close the application". It's possible this could be a security update.

Closing Firefox doesn't actually seem to help anything. The message returns with the same number of days remaining until it will refresh the snap.

This problem seems related only to the Firefox snap.

Comment: Quit Firefox, then run `sudo snap refresh`

Comment: The notification is there to prevent worse alternatives, like Firefox terminating (and losing all unsaved work) when the countdown reaches zero in order to update. That's what used to happen with the Firefox snap before 22.04. Developers are aware that it's a problem (the notification bugs them, too) and have been working on several ideas to improve the snap-refresh experience.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Unfortunately after reading the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412140/how-to-solve-pending-update-of-firefox-snap-close-the-app-to-avoid-disruptio) provided by someone else and reading it in rising astonishment, I am unfortunately out of patience with snap and have removed it entirely from my system.

I understand `sudo snap refresh`, possibly combined with `killall firefox` and strange snap update scheduling commands, could also have solved my problem. But this and other poor UX of the firefox snap is just so bad, I now prefer having a non-standard install.