# Chromium Snap Updating

Tags: updates, chromium, notification

I am confused about the 13 day timer re snap chromium update.  I have read the update takes place only after the 13 day has run, and then it just crashes the app if it is running and updates. I've also read this only applies if the pc is never powered down (e.g. a server).  What exactly happens if said pc is powered down daily (as per most household Desktop machines)?  Is this 13 day timer relevant?  I am assuming the user will get a notification that an update is available; if the user does nothing at this point (ignores the update message) and powers down at the end of the day will the update take place the following day when the machine is powered on? Ideally I would like to turn the notifications off and the updating to take place at the next power down/up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "Pending update of "firefox" snap. Close the app to avoid disruptions" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412140/how-to-solve-pending-update-of-firefox-snap-close-the-app-to-avoid-disruptio)

Comment: Not really - there are many comments about using terminal commands to verify updates and moans about the whole process.  I am happy with the terminal but I'm looking for a solution for a technophobe who just wants to use the pc without any user input for 'system things' (updates being one of these).  If the user does nothing (after the notification) will Chromium update itself during the daily power down/up process?

Comment: Chromium will update itself if necessary with an unattended upgrade. In the accepted answer to the linked duplicate question it says `which means you have 13 days to upgrade Firefox yourself or else the Firefox snap package will get an unattended upgrade`, but it works the same way for the Chromium snap package as it does for the Firefox snap package.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. So the answer to:  If the user does nothing (after the notification) will Chromium update itself during the daily power down/up          is YES

Comment: It'll just *nag* at you until the time has elapsed, the *snap* package (chromium) will be forced closed & update when the time limit has been exceeded (*it checks only when power is on of course*). If you're using it at the time, it just closes & any unsaved data is lost, so its recommended to not reach the time-limit. All *snap* packages are treated equally.. What little adjustments you can make aren't worth fighting with in my opinion, just close it when convenient for you & run `snap refresh` (*ideally not in last day/hours*).  If you reboot once per fortnight, do it then for example :)

Comment: If the box is powered off for 12 hours per day & on for 12 hours - that timer still treats that as 1 day (24 hours..) as it uses the system clock time (*not powered on time*), so suspended/hibernated or on all day the result is the same; only difference being it'll force upgrade when box is next powered on after time period has elapsed (*potential loss of data if you've entered fields but not saved etc*)...

Comment: My understanding then is to switch off notifications, so the user doesn't know what is going on. And then, unknown to the user, after 13 days the application will update itself when the Desktop is next powered on. (Assuming the pc is powered on/off daily as per normal).

Comment: I'd not advise switching off notifications; I suggest you leave them on!  Some in the Ubuntu project value security very highly (*which is a good thing!*) and the notifications are there to prompt you to apply the security fixes to keep yourself secure.  Where you've told the notifications to display to me matters, they're too annoying on my primary monitor so I have them on a far corner of another monitor, I note & igore them until I've finished whatever I'm doing, about to change what I do or go to lunch, then close app(s) it wants to upgrade, open term & `snap refresh`.

Comment: On the odd occasion I get an error where `snap refresh` doesn't see anything to refresh; usual cause is the snap didn't fully close (it has permissions to run in the background), so I check that's not occurring (some apps like `telegram-desktop` have panel close option) or force quit app at terminal & then perform refresh. I then go to lunch, start my new task etc.. The refresh maybe 15 mins after the notification, 3 hours later, sometimes days later...  ie. I do it as soon as I consider I can without it interrupting what I'm trying to do. FYI:  No pain in asking; we all need to learn